# What values of $\delta$ make this statement true?

Tags: inequality, continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

Let $\epsilon >0$

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha > 0$ and

\begin{align*}
|1-\alpha| &\leq \delta \\
|\beta| &\leq \delta
\end{align*}

For what $\delta > 0$ will 
\begin{align*}
\big{|} \frac{\beta}{\alpha}\big{|} < \epsilon
\end{align*} hold?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\alpha\geq 1-\delta$, and $|\beta|\leq \delta$, you get the desired inequality if
$$
\frac{\delta}{1-\delta} < \epsilon
$$
which happens if $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$.